# Write charAt method for string

Tags: java, split

`Having problems in the if statement. It kept on giving me
Error: incomparable types: java.lang.String and int. 
How do I go about this?

`String str = "helloworld";`  // At main method of my program

```
public static String charAt(int index) {
    String result = "";
    int lol;
    String[] list = str.split("");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if(list[i] == index) {
        result += list[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pretty clear error message.

```
if(list[i] == index)
```

You cannot do that since both are not comparable. list[i] is a string and index is an int.

Probably you want

`if(i==index)` it seems

Comment: @Aurora_Titanium This does not *solve* the problem, it merely *hides* it. The real problem is that you are using a loop in a situation where you do not need any iteration at all. Think about it: you will call `result += list[i];` at most once - i.e. when `i` reaches `index` (unless `index` is too high). Let's say `index` is 40. There's no point in checking in a loop if `0==40`, then if `1==40`, then if `2==40`, and so on, because you know that `40` is equal `40` and no other number. A correct solution requires getting rid of the loop.

Comment: I made some changes. Tell me what you think of this

 public static char charAt(int index)
  {
    char result = ' ';
    
    char[] charlist = str.toCharArray();
      for(int i = 0; i < charlist.length; i++)
      {
        if(i == index)
        {
          result = charlist[i];
        }
      }
    return result;
  }

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `for` loop at all: simply return `list[index]` as your result.

```
String[] list = str.split("");
if (list.length > index) {
    return list[index];
}
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Comment: I didn't see any explanation for current error message and no correction for OP code and simply giving working code. Phew.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I would explain what he did wrong if OP needed to keep any of that code. I mean, there is no need to fix the comparison, because that comparison does not need to be there in the first place.